# light stays on even after disconnecting switch

Tags: light-fixture

Have a light that's been working fine for years. Two switches control the light on opposite sides of the room. All of the sudden light will not turn off. Disconnected both switches and light stays on. Tested voltage at both switches and get almost nothing or just a few volts. At first I swore the meter was jumping over 150 volts to OL but not anymore. Get 120 volts at light bulb socket.  Light is hung via hook from 18 foot ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a short (hot to switched) that is providing power directly to the light, bypassing the switches. Start with checking any junction boxes or splices, and any exposed wiring that might have been gnawed on by animals. Or if you have had carpenters/construction (amateur or professional) when the problem started, suspect a nail through a cable.

Comment: Thx. Only recent changes r new bulbs in the fixture and added a 1500 watt floor heater in same room not same breaker. Plenty of nails in the wall but not since last year. I put up the light in place of fan 3 years ago...will go back and rent the tressel ladder and get up top. Unfortunately no crawl space above it. I'm worried this is not going to be easy or may cost me a professional. In meantime is this dangerous...I've turned off breaker just in case for overnight peace of mind.

Comment: @tropicrocket yes it is potentially dangerous.  A short that is making a bad (high resistance) connection can make enough heat to start a fire.  Good call turning off the breaker until you work out what is going on.

Comment: Found it. The neutral at hanging fixture was crimped and touching junction box in ceiling. Taped it up and all is good. Thx!